# How does one create a dialog box for Facebook IFrame applications that can be closed programmatically?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to create a dialog box for my Facebook IFRAME application which I then can close programmatically via Javascript. I cannot create the dialog via a Javascript library such as jQuery because I need to embed a particular FBML tag within the dialog.

**Approach 1**: Via the current Javascript SDK. This doesn't provide me with any way to close it except by clicking the **X** button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var content = .... // my fbml content
    var dialog = {
                method:'fbml.dialog',
                display: 'dialog',
                fbml: content, 
        };
    FB.ui(dialog);
</script>
```

**Approach 2**: Via XFBML and a whole lot of divs and css to imitate a FB dialog box. However, I can't seem to add Javascript inside the serverfbml tags which means there's no way to programmatically show or hide it.

```
<fb:serverfbml>
   <script type="text/fbml">
      <fbml>
      <div> .... </div>
      </fbml>
   </script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

Are there any approaches that can possibly create such a dialog box?

Comment: Why do you need js inside serverfbml? Can it be just outside of it?

Comment: The serverfbml is parsed and displayed in its own iframe. JS outside it doesn't work on the elements in that iframe.

Comment: But do you just want to hide it all? Why not just hide serverfbml's parent element?

Comment: I need to implement a cancel button inside the dialog which will close the dialog itself by setting the style of the parent div to "display:none". JS functions outside the generated FBML cannot be called by that button as the HTML elements within the serverfbml get processed by FB and their ids and function calls are then prepended with the FB application ID. I haven't thought of your suggestion to manipulate the parent element directly, will try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a standard dialog box that includes your FBML. Call XFBML.Parse() when you open your dialog and it should work fine. If you need a leg up with a reasonable dialog jQuery control, Boxy is pretty good.